# ECMAScript Modules On Node.js v11.9.0

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to use exports and import on Node.js application, So I used the Node.js documentation [ECMAScript Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_interop_with_existing_modules). But I am getting error

I am using,

- v11.9.0
- Run command `node --experimental-modules app.js`

How can I use ES6 export and import in Node.JS ? Preferred me the way that not using any additional package !

**Code :**

```
// test.js
module.exports = { one: 1 };

// app.js
import foo from './test.js';
console.log(foo);
```

**Error :**

```
(node:9352) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
/home/Workspace/test/app.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import foo from './test.js';
                                                                     ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:84:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:264:10)
    at Proxy.runInThisContext (vm.js:312:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:694:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:558:3)
    at createDynamicModule (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:73:15)
    at Object.meta.done (internal/modules/esm/create_dynamic_module.js:40:9)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) says your files need a `.mjs` extension:

> The --experimental-modules flag can be used to enable features for
>   loading ESM modules.
>
> Once this has been set, files ending with .mjs will be able to be
>   loaded as ES Modules.

You have to currently use the flag and there is no "seamless" way to use them at the moment other than using a transpiler like babel.

As Quentin says CommonJS files can still use .js extension (you can mix and match).

Comment: Only `app.js` needs that extension, `test.js` is a CommonJS module not an ES Module.

Comment: Yes, Its worked when I renamed to `app.mjs`. In further stable release still we need to have ext as `.mjs` to use  import ? Can I use by changing file name or use babel for project (recommend) ?

Comment: Babel is useful when you want to use modules made for the UI or for example pre-render an app like one made in React. Because the two module systems are not interopable (have some behaviour differences) I'm not sure if they will make them the same. Using babel adds more setup and increases the start up time and memory of your application, so I would use it only if you have a reason to.